# What happened with the project of the Genie of the Staff?

Tags: rwby

Obviously, this question involves major spoilers for plot points from Volume 8. Near the end of the volume, the main team calls forth the Genie of the Staff (or Ambrosius, or the Blue Fairy, or whatever his title might be) and ask him to create a particular project.
That scene seemed rather confusing. Specifically, Ruby originally asks him to create an exact copy of

> Penny, using her existing components, then seems to specify that .

Her Aura or soul would transmigrate to the new body, which presumably would ensure that she was the "same" person to the extent possible.

However, Penny's new body seems to be made of flesh and blood. While the visual and dialogue clues could potentially be viewed as ambiguous, she *is* based on Pinnochio. Moreover, the robot body still continues to exist after her new body is created, which suggests that Ambrosius did not use the parts to create her new body, which he might have been incapable of in any case, since he says that he cannot destroy, only create.

That might lead one to think that Ambrosius only used her original body as the *schematic* for the new body, but Ruby definitely thought that anything that Ambrosius created directly would last only until he began a new project, and Penny's new body continues to exist even after Ambrosius turns his attention to his next task. Ruby's statement would fit with what we saw happen to Atlas: the moment Ambrosius began to create something else, it started falling. For that matter, setting aside concerns about how long his projects would last, Ambrosius *couldn't* have created an exact copy of her as he was asked to: a human body is not an exact copy of a robot, except superficially.

To cap it all off, the *original robot body* seems to dissolve at the exact same moment that Ambrosius creates the portals, which would suggest that somehow *that* was what he had created—which obviously makes no sense whatsoever.

So what exactly was going on? How do all of these events fit together?

Comment: Any hints as to what series this is in reference to?

Comment: That is what tags are for.